# how to add 6% tax on four product based on there product id

Tags: magento-1.9

how to add tax 6% on 4 product using there product id and where to write these code i am new in Magento ver. 1.9.0.0 please  help me. product id is 301,504,709,935

Answer (score 1):

You could add a new tax type under:

```
Sales -> Tax -> Produt Tax Classes
```

and then add those products to that tax class.
Then add a new tax rule.

Comment: i want custom code i dont  want to use  admin panel